# VMare Fusion 3 and Visual Studio 2010 problem with Shared Folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vmware

Hi I have problem using Shared Folder in VMare Fusion 3 and Visual Studio 2010.

When I use ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool I receive and error
"Failed to start monitoring changes to 'Z:\MSDOS......."

I suppose ASP.NET it is not able to access the Shared Folder with the right permission.

Some one has the same problem? How to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, virtualized Win 7 and love it in all respects except this one. I get an error loading VS (can't find .vssettings, errors when I try and create same) and then the "failed to start monitoring changes" error when trying to run an ASP.NET website (any, not just the admin tool).

The only article I found online about this problem is this one:  http://alextafoya.com/post/2009/08/19/Make-Visual-Studio-work-with-VMWare-Fusion-shares.aspx#comment

But when I try and follow the instructions, the first step (registry change) doesn't affect anything and the second change I can't do b/c I don't have the SDk installed, and get a "not a valid win32 application" error when I try and install it.

Very frustrating.

Comment: Hi Paul, if I can advices you. You should work with VS & DataBase on C in the Virtual machine. You can use the SHARED FOLDER to backup your file on MAC. For example I use SubVersion to update my Repository on the SHARED FOLDER. This means you can work fully granted in Windows (with no problem in permission) and keep copy as backup using SVN and Time Machine on your MAC. I hope can help.

Comment: No, I know I can do this, but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Hi, have you find a solution to your problem? bye

Comment: Yes!  The SDK issue was a result of the host OS blocking the download; so I was getting only a partial file. Once that was done, and I followed those instructions, it worked. The only issue I now have is that I still can't run off IIS through VS, but if I'm using the embedded web server, w're good.